# How to enable file-based authentication in CAS 5

Tags: cas

I'm standing up a standalone CAS 5 instance on my local machine for tinkering/hacking and I'm trying to get it set up as a standalone WAR file deployed to Tomcat with a simple file-based authentication.

Starting with the WAR Overlay template (https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template), I've added the following dependency as indicated at https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.0.x/installation/Whitelist-Authentication.html#example-password-file.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
      <artifactId>cas-server-support-generic</artifactId>
      <version>${cas.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I then created a simple `passwd.txt` file with the following contents in `src/main/resources`.

```
bob::bob
alice::alice
```

Finally, I added the file-based properties (c.f. https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.0.x/installation/Configuration-Properties.html#file-authentication) to `etc/cas/config/cas.properties`.

```
cas.authn.file.filename=classpath:passwd.txt
cas.authn.accept.users=
cas.authn.file.passwordEncoder.type=NONE
cas.authn.file.separator=::
```

When I deploy the application, the app starts up, but the only user that is accepted at the login form is `casuser` / `Mellon` (the defaults). I even tried tacking on the property `cas.authn.policy.any.tryAll=true` to the `cas.properties` file, but neither Alice nor Bob is recognized.

Is there somewhere different I should be setting these options? Is there something else I need to do to enable file-based authentication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After spending way too much time on this problem, I wanted to save anyone else the headaches. The key here was that I was modifying `/etc/cas/config/cas.properties`. This did not have the intended effect when compiling a standalone WAR to deploy on a servlet container. My guess (without verification) is that this works a bit differently if you are creating an executable JAR.

What I ended up doing was commenting out all entries in `/etc/cas/config/cas.properties` and moving them to `/src/main/resources/application.properties`. This had an effect, but caused some obscure errors about `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot create binder factory, no META-INF/spring.binders resources found on the classpath`.

I followed the suggestion at https://groups.google.com/a/apereo.org/d/msg/cas-user/doLj6Aa10u8/2o9urrQpCwAJ and copied the default configuration to `/src/main/resources/application.properties`, added `cas.authn.*` options above, rebuilt, redeployed and everything worked.

It seems like the best way to go with setting up a standalone WAR overlay is to take the provided template, copy the default settings from the CAS source code (https://github.com/apereo/cas/blob/958a9fbb87fb728875a7a35ee45124e818f90b17/webapp/resources/application.properties at this writing), add the Maven dependencies indicated by the docs, then add/modify the properties to get the effect you want.